# "heatmaps" vs. "a heatmap"

Tags: word-usage

This image comes from a [post](https://blog.mapbox.com/visualizing-the-progression-of-the-2019-ncov-outbreak-66763eb59e79) where the original image is a video gif.

[image]

How do I refer to this thing in this particular situation?

> image xx shows **a heatmap**

or

> image xx shows some heatmaps

when to which?

Answer (score 1):

**heatmap** is singular and would be used when refering to ONE item, the whole graphic.

You would use the plural **heatmaps** if referring to more then one graphic. An example might be: "I read an article that has several **heatmaps** of Southeast Asia."

Or you could also use **heatmaps** with this one graphic, if the subject is each individual country shown, rather then the graphic as a whole. "This graphic shows the **heatmaps** of the countries in Southeast Asia."